# hm-swipe-up/down doesn't work Angular-gestures

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gesture, hammer.js

**Hi All,**
I created simple app with angular js here is the app:

http://plnkr.co/edit/7qPOYzlJSqsG7O1Ihwqt?p=preview

I have a problem to swipe it up and down, but drag up and down works fine.
also I have min and max value that stop incrimination or decrimination of the value when I 
taping on the buttons but it dosent working on drag and swipe.
Please review this code if some one knows what I done wrong   
Thanks.